# TimeStamp Conversion From HexaDecimal

Tags: sql-server, timestamp

How can I convert a hexadecimal timestamp to date time in SQL server.
I tried Cast/Convert but it throws error.

Regards,
Rahul

Answer (score 2):

You can't. "The Transact-SQL timestamp data type is different from the timestamp data type defined in the SQL-2003 standard. The SQL-2003 timestamp data type is equivalent to the Transact-SQL datetime data type." and "The timestamp data type is just an incrementing number and does not preserve a date or a time. To record a date or time, use a datetime data type." [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

And also: "The timestamp syntax is deprecated. This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature." [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql)